# Is there a way for directives to inherit behavior from another directive within an AngularJs application?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to create a dashboard like page with Angular and as soon as I started to code the widgets from the main page, it was obvious I was repeating code between them.

Basically, all widgets have some "data", a template for presenting that data and a "loading" property (true while request is ongoing to display an animated icon inside its container).

However, templates itself are different amongst widgets. Since templates, are different, data handling and (possibly) manipulation is also different.

Ok, so, this means different controllers per widget. But can I share the basic behavior between them? Like executing a request, setting "loading" to "true", handle/manipulate response, set loading to false, present template.

How scenarios like that work with Angular 1.x?

I appreciate any help figuring out the topics I need to look into for that to work.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441500/extending-base-directive-functionality-to-other-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is to have a base controller that is vm that contains all the base functionality, and then there will be a child View that is the directive and usually does not have an isolate scope, so it can see vm and use its functionality (but you can also pass it in as part of the directive definition).

If you imagine it without directives for a second, it might look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="parent as vm">
   <div ng-controller="child">...</div>
</div>
```

And the controllers might look like:

```
app.module('someModule').controller('parent', ['dataService', parent])
.controller('child', ['$scope', child]);

function parent(dataService) {
   var vm = this;
   var dataCollection = dataService.collection;
   vm.findTheData = function(value) {
     return dataCollection.indexOf(value);
   }
}

function child($scope) {
    $scope.dataIndex = -1;
    $scope.onButtonClicked = function(value) {
        if ($scope.vm) $scope.dataIndex = vm.findTheData(value);
    }
}
```